# List out the required files from an Unix directory

Tags: unix, file-listing

I have files in a unix directory as shown below

```
XMP.df.a.xml
XPL.dg.a.xml
XMP.sf.b.xml
XPL.ba.b.xml
XMP.ad.c.xml
XPL.lk.b.xml
```

I have to list out the files that have both "XMP" and "b" in its name.

I tried `ls -ltr XMP* *b*`
But it displays all the 'XMP' as well as 'b' results.

Is there a way to list only the files that has XMP and b in it's name?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ls -ltr XMP*b*` might suffice.

Comment: if the files format is fixed you can use below as well:
ls -ltr XMP.??.b.xml

Comment: Yes.. File format is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is causing you headaches. What you have right now is asking ls to look for two different sets of files; `XMP*` **and** `*b*` in the current directory. What you want is:

```
ls -ltr XMP*b*
```

No space.